# Understand Fluent Selenium Wait

Tags: java, selenium, automated-tests, selenium-webdriver, fluent

I am into Development and new to QA/Automation testing. 
I am trying to understand the following code;

```java
public WebElement getVisibleElement( final By by, final WebElement parentElement, int timeoutValue, TimeUnit timeoutPeriod, int pollingInterval, TimeUnit pollingPeriod ) {
    return fluentWait(timeoutValue, timeoutPeriod, pollingInterval, pollingPeriod).until( new Function<WebDriver, WebElement>() {
        public WebElement apply(WebDriver driver) {
            try {
            } catch {
            }
            return null; 
        }
    });
}
```

In my same class, I also have;

```java
public Wait<WebDriver> fluentWait(int timeoutValue, TimeUnit timeoutPeriod, int pollingInterval, TimeUnit pollingPeriod) {

    return new FluentWait<WebDriver>(this.webDriver)
                        .withTimeout(timeoutValue, timeoutPeriod)
                        .pollingEvery(pollingInterval, pollingPeriod)
                        .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);
}
```

Specifically 2 things I wanted to understand;

1. What is return fluentWait() doing exactly?
2. What does the use of until() mean here?

Answer (score 2):

They tie in together so I won't answer them separately as such:

Selenium's `FluentWait` approach is generally just to wait for a certain condition to be true. You can give it a number of different possible conditions and it will keep evaluating it until it's true or your timeout value is passed, whichever is first.

a) `return`, in most programming languages is just returning *something* from a method.

b) `until` is the method you call on the `FluentWait` to have it physically evaluate a condition. Everything before that, is just setting it up, using `.until(....)` is telling the `FluentWait` instance to go and evaluate the code I'm giving you. In your case, I assume by the name of the method (the actual method is incomplete), by calling `.until(....)` you are telling the `FluentWait` to keep trying to grab an element from the page until it's physically visible to the user.

The `fluentWait` method is merely setting up a `FluentWait` instance to use, whilst the `apply/until` code section is setting up what **condition** you want to evaluate. In your `getVisibleElement` method you are returning a `WebElement`, so in your `apply` code section, you'll need to return the `WebElement` once you are satisfied it's visible to the user.

What I would assume you would want to do within the `apply`, is find the element using the normal `.findElement` and check it's `visible` property. If it's true, return the `WebElement` found, if not, return `null` to force the `FluentWait` to keep going.

The `return fluentWait` therefore, is merely saying "return whatever this `FluentWait` returns". Which, since the method has been already declared as returning a `WebElement` instance, you are therefore saying "return whatever WebElement this `FluentWait` returns".